# Request validation using swagger

Tags: yaml, swagger-2.0

I need to validate incoming REST request using swagger(YAML file) in java. So can anyone help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating REST messages against Swagger definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41037719/113116), [Is there a way to use Swagger just for validation without using the whole framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488357/113116), [Validating JSON messages against Swagger definition in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43760008/113116).

Comment: Actually my swagger file is a YAML file. The link provided has a solution for JSON swagger. So can u help me how to validate using YAML file.

Comment: "JSON" in those questions refers to the request format, not Swagger definition format.

Answer (score -1):

> SwaggerValidationInterceptor

has a constructor which accepts Byte array. See below:

```
public SwaggerValidationInterceptor(final EncodedResource swaggerInterface) throws IOException {
        this(new SwaggerRequestValidationService(swaggerInterface));
    }
```

So you can do it, by converting your **yaml** file to as a Byte array and then passing it to Swagger.

To convert it to Byte Array, you can follow below approach:

```
public SwaggerValidationInterceptor swaggerValidationInterceptor(Resource swaggerDescriptor) throws IOException {
        final byte[] yamlPathAsBytes = swaggerDescriptor.getFile().getAbsolutePath().getBytes(UTF_8);
        return new SwaggerValidationInterceptor(
                new EncodedResource(new ByteArrayResource(yamlPathAsBytes), UTF_8));
    }
```

Comment: Dropping just the name SwaggerValidationInterceptor does not help much. This interceptor belongs to the swagger-request-validator library (link?!). It is the adaptor for a Spring MVC application. The unspecific question did not mention any Spring. So it is just a guess.