# Validating JSON response given a Swagger

Tags: json, swagger

I would like to test if the response in JSON format is conform to a given a Swagger definition.

Is there any tool that given a swagger and a response is doing this job for me?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating JSON against Swagger API schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275947/validating-json-against-swagger-api-schema), [Is there a way to use Swagger just for validation without using the whole framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488357/113116) and [Validating REST messages against Swagger definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41037719/113116)